# Registry GetSubKeyNames() lists different keys than Regedit?

Tags: c#, wix, registry

We are using WIX to install a number of services we create. I am writing a quick utility to dump the currently installed services. I just iterate over subkeys of:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

looking for `DisplayName`. The problem is, only two of my ten services show up in the list.

However, when I look at the subkeys in Regedit, they are there. As well, they are in the installed programs (and I can find them in SELECT * from Win32_Product too).

I looked through the MSDN docs, trying to find out if there is some special view of the registry that I am missing. Maybe it is a privilege issue? But I am running the tool as admin. Is there some hive mounting issue?

Just to be clear with the code, here is the test app code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system)):

```
String registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey))
{
  foreach(String subkeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    Console.WriteLine(key.OpenSubKey(subkeyName).GetValue("DisplayName"));
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Also, you should tag this as "Wix".

Comment: Also, please don't repeat the tags ("C#") in the title. I'm sure you don't think that `GetSubKeyNames` is a C# method, but the title read that way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is a 32/64 bit issue. It seems that some of the installations happened under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\...
```

When I enumerate them both, I get all of my installations.

Apparently I can also use `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey()` with a `RegistryView.Registry64/32` instead of the `Wow6432Node` too.