# GetSubKeyNames function return diffrent subkeys in C# and Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, registry, registrykey

I am using GetSubKeysNames function to get subkey from {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall}. But it returns diffrent subkeys count. In C# returns 371 subkeys, in visual basic returns 61 subkeys. Where am i wrong?

Here is some code and pic.

C#

```
string[] deneme = unistallKey.GetSubKeyNames();
```

[image]

VB

```
Dim deneme() As String = UninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112181/registry-getsubkeynames-lists-different-keys-than-regedit

Comment: What is `UninstallKey`? you should post the code where you obtain the sub key's not where you'r using them.

Comment: Unistallkey is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and i want to get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall's subkeys. I am not using, i am trying to obtain them here.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and using the code below, the problem was solved.

```
 Dim rk1 As RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey _
                                    (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64)
        Dim rk2 As RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey _
                                    (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64)
        Dim rk3 As RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey _
                                    (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64)

    rk1 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)

    regpath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

    rk2 = rk1.OpenSubKey(regpath)

    For Each subk As String In rk2.GetSubKeyNames

        rk3 = rk2.OpenSubKey(subk, False)

        value = rk3.GetValue("DisplayName", "")

        If value <> "" Then
            includes = True
            If value.IndexOf("Hotfix") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Security Update") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Update for") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Service Pack") <> -1 Then includes = False

            For vAtual = 0 To UBound(Softwares)
                If value = Softwares(vAtual) Then
                    includes = False
                End If
            Next

            If includes = True Then
                gridSoft.Rows.Add(value, rk3.GetValue("InstallDate", ""), rk3.GetValue("UninstallString", ""), rk3.GetValue("EstimatedSize", ""), rk3.GetValue("InstallLocation", ""), rk3.GetValue("Publisher", ""))
                Softwares(vCont) = value
                vCont = vCont + 1
            End If

        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some of your programs are installed under 32 bit and some are under 64 bit. 
Enumerate through the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432node\

Comment: i am checking both of them but the issue is in under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall