# I'm having a strange issue searching the registry using GetSubKeyNames

Tags: vb.net

I want to search the registry to see if key names exist. One location is **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID**. I used the RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames to do my search, and the following code to verify it was working.

```
Dim key1 As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID")
Dim key1SubKeySearch As String = String.Empty
For Each key1SubKeySearch In key1.GetSubKeyNames
        MsgBox(key1SubKeySearch)
Next
```

I thought I might be having the problem of this user: [Registry GetSubKeyNames() lists different keys than Regedit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112181/registry-getsubkeynames-lists-different-keys-than-regedit) I tried his suggestion but it doesn't work either...

```
classesRootBase = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Default)
```

I still have missing results. I'm not sure what view I'm supposed to choose, perhaps that's causing my issue.

Comment: What results are you missing?

Comment: I had it output a list the keys in this location, and it does not match up with what I see in regedit.