# how to find out the path of the program using c#

Tags: c#

I found a snippet of code explaining how to use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to run an external program in C#. The snippet shows running `cmd.exe`, which is in the path.

Let's assume that there is some external program (Beyond Compare for example). I don't know if it is installed on the PC. How can I check if this program is installed using C#? If the program is installed, I would like to find the path so that I can launch it.

Comment: There are a couple of different things you can do, check the registry for any added registry keys(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall). Or assuming most programs are installed in the Program Files directory, you can get the Program files path by using the system variable %ProgramFiles%. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I think the downvote was done because your question was not clear.

Comment: Removed the code sample because it was misleading.

Comment: @Aidan Ryan: why is the code sample misleading?  It at least indicates that the OP knows how to run a program from C# (thus preempting a spate of answers along the lines of "here's how to use Process.Start()"), but wants to know how to expand that to finding an installed program and then running it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system

Comment: @siride Just a mention of Process.Start is enough. Sample was 80% of the body of the questin.

Comment: @roymustang86 and @MehdiHadjar refer us to iterating the list of installed programs under `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` -- that's the closest to an answer to the actual question. It will at least allow you to detect if the program is installed, **IF** you know its Program Code GUID or DisplayName. From there, if InstallLocation is set you can at least know the path where the executable *may* reside. You still are required to know the actual executable filename and it requires more rights than app launch. (@roymustang86 - be careful with %programfiles% on 64 bit systems)

Comment: Yeah, I actually have run into that problem while writing auto update program for a 32 bit application. When installed on a 64 bit system, they were installed in the ProgramFiles(x86) folder, and it kept downloading the file over and over and failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're trying to see if a program exists where you're looking for it (like BeyondCompare.exe), you can just use a call to:

`System.IO.File.Exists("path_to_program.exe");`

If it returns true, then you know your program exists and you can run it with your process runner code.  If it returns false, then you know it's not there and you shouldn't launch your process.

If I'm misunderstanding your question, please let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Thanks.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Apparently there's someone on the loose downvoting without explanation.

Comment: OP doesn't know the path to the executable. File.Exists is not relevant. (BTW, I'm not the downvoter...)

Answer (score 5):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system), which directed me to this [this article](http://www.thereforesystems.com/get-a-list-of-installed-applications-using-linq-and-c/). 
I've modified the source for readability, and to solve your problem specifically (note that I've guessed the description and executable name of Beyond Compare.)

You can call it like this, from your `main`:

```
string path = FindAppPath("Beyond Compare"); 
if (path == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to find program path.");
    return;
}
path += "BeyondCompare.exe";
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    Process beyondCompare = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = path + "BeyondCompare.exe",
            Arguments = string.Empty // You may need to specify args.
        }
    };
    beyondCompare.Start();
}
```

The source for `FindAppPath` follows:

```
static string FindAppPath(string appName)
{
    // If you don't use contracts, check this and throw ArgumentException
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appName));
    const string keyPath =
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath))
    {
        var installed = 
            (from skName in key.GetSubKeyNames()
            let subkey = key.OpenSubKey(skName)
            select new
            {
                name = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string,
                path = subkey.GetValue("InstallLocation") as string

            }).ToList();

        var desired = installed.FindAll(
            program => program.name != null && 
            program.name.Contains(appName)  &&
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(program.path));

        return (desired.Count > 0) ? desired[0].path : null;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this method returns the *first* matching path, so don't feed it an `appName` argument that's too generic (eg. "Microsoft") or you probably won't get what you're looking for.

Comment: Won't this return: "path"BeyondCompare.exe instead of "path\BeyondCompare.exe" ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic to do for this.

```
string filepath = "c:\windows\test.exe";
bool bOk = false;
try
{
  bOk = System.IO.File.Exists(filepath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }
if (!bOk)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid Path");
}
else
{
   Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c dir *.cs";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine("Output:");
    Console.WriteLine(output);    
}
```

Comment: @Rob: I can't speak for the answerer, but my guess is that they left it blank because it's not important to the answer (and specific to the context anyway).  It would have been better, of course, to leave a comment indicating that appropriate action should be taken.

Comment: @siride: Comments would have been just as good, but either way, he edited and I've removed my down-vote.

Comment: OP doesn't know the path to the executable. File.Exists is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't need to make that check. Simply start the program without path (only the filename) and set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true`.

Windows will look for the app in its list of installed app. If it doesn't find it, `Process.Start()`will fail. The interesting thing is that you never had to care about where the app is stored.