# C# Application Scanning

Tags: c#, executable

I want to scan and get all the Application files in my computer.
I know how to get them, but I want only the applications which are Executable (except for Installers).

Basically, what I want is the same function steam uses.
Example:
[image]

Comment: you mean installed Applications ??? or any "Executable files" are stored in your hardDrive ??

Comment: What kind of applications are _not_ Executable?

Comment: All exe are Executable, but I meant something else. There're exe which close as soon as you run them and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the list of installed applications on your system, you can query the registry. Refer to [Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system) for an example.

Comment: I know how to get the installed applications. I am pretty sure Steam uses this solution combined with some filters and more function, but I cant find out how they do it exactly...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to find all exes recursively in a directory

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files");
    var exeFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach ( var exeFile in exeFiles )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( exeFile );
    }
```

Depending on you definition of executable you might have to also do `*.com` , `*.bat` etc etc. There is no way to distinguish between an installer exe vs regular exe file though. You might have to apply some heuristics

Comment: As I said, I know how to scan the apps. I dont know how to decide if it's installer or not.. anyway I dont think that's the way Steam uses.