# is their an alternative method to retrieve the Installed products ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wmi

```
public class Property
     {
         public string Name{ get; set; }
         public string Value{ get; set; }
     }

 List<Property> info = GetSystemInfo("Win32_ComputerSystem", "*", "", "System");
 info = GetSystemInfo("win32_Product", "*", "", "Product");
```

I am using the above code to fetch the List of installed products . But Its taking quite a long. Actually I didn't see it complete the operation:( 
could anyone please suggest a quick way of fetching the installed product list ?

Comment: You should have searched first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/908907/555547. WMI is usually slow, at least it's first run.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this takes a while depending on how many software are stored. Sometimes it may take up to 5 minutes and more. If the machine you're quering supports SNMP I recommend using that protocol, you will gather fewer information (only name, id, type and install date actually) but at least it will be almost instant.

This is the MIB OID:

http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.6.3.1