# How to get installed software details from windows registry?

Tags: c#, installation, registry, windows-installer, exe

I am developing an application for installing software from exe or msi file.
After Installation I want installed software details from registry in C#,
so that I can use that details for uninstallation of the software.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system) to similar question

You should look at uninstal registry entries:

"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
in current user and local machine

Comment: Yes but i should have display name or any unique identity of the software in these registry entries. I have only exe or msi of software. how do i identify the name of the software?

Comment: The simple way is to look at file properties, but i am not shure, that all installers have this fields filled. Another way is to parse msi or exe file for this information, but it will not be easy

Comment: File property does not work because all setups dont have properties created. How can we parse msi or exe?? Please help...