# Detecting the time when the program was installed

Tags: .net, winapi, registry

Can I somehow detect the time when the program was installed using .Net or Win32 api or any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get the date of the Installation, I'm not sure of you can get time

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
    foreach(string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("InstallDate"));
        }
    }
}
```

you can use all these fields

[image: registry entries]

for more info refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system) answer.

you can get time by Using Windows Installer API!
the function to be used is [MsiGetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the property name is **INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLDATE** but WMI is heavyweight.

here is more info for this property taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLDATE**: *The last time this product received service. The value of this property is replaced each time a patch is applied or removed from the product or the /v Command-Line Option is used to repair the product. If the product has received no repairs or patches this property contains the time this product was installed on this computer.*

**Example:**

```
[DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern Int32 MsiGetProductInfo(string product, string property, [Out] StringBuilder valueBuf, ref Int32 len);

Int32 len = 512;
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(len);
MsiGetProductInfo("{4B3334CE-06D9-4446-BBC5-EB4C9D75BFF6}", "INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLDATE", builder , ref len);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find it in registry.

Thats why its not about `.NET` or `WinAPI`.

For example:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate
```

shows you the istallation time of your `Windows` in seconds since 01.01.1970