# Alternative to Win32_Product?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi-query

After playing around with querying `Win32_Product` to find a software version, I couldn't understand why the results were so dog-slow. As much as 15 times slower than querying `Win32_service` or `Win32_process`. So coming here to see if I'm missing something, I find that others have reported the same issue, and this [article](http://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/) explains why.

The most-often suggested alternative to finding installed software is querying a registry entry or three. That was going to be my first solution, except my company hasn't moved to configure servers to accept `PSRemoting` yet. Any reg queries just return Kerberos authentication errors. I can enable `PSRemoting` on individual servers, but my team supports 30K systems. So that solution is out.

Bottom line, we're upgrading Symantec Endpoint Protection from v. 11 to v. 12, and I want a simple check to find what version is installed on a server. Are there any alternatives to find the version other than `Win32_Product` and registry queries?

Comment: You can get the properties of installed software from the executable. `Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Software\file.exe' | select -expand versioninfo`

Comment: An explanation why it is slow can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315976/33244). Spoiler alert: it runs a MSI package validation. Because... reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the registry remotely, without PSRemoting.  Here's the function I wrote and use daily to query software.

```
Function Get-RemoteSoftware{
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
Displays all software listed in the registry on a given computer.

.DESCRIPTION
Uses the SOFTWARE registry keys (both 32 and 64bit) to list the name, version, vendor, and uninstall string for each software entry on a given computer.

.EXAMPLE
C:\PS> Get-RemoteSoftware -ComputerName SERVER1
This shows the software installed on SERVER1.
#>

param (
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string[]]
    # Specifies the computer name to connect to
    $ComputerName
)

Process {
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
    {
        #Open Remote Base
        $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer)

        #Check if it's got 64bit regkeys
        $keyRootSoftware = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
        [bool]$is64 = ($keyRootSoftware.GetSubKeyNames() | ? {$_ -eq 'WOW6432Node'} | Measure-Object).Count
        $keyRootSoftware.Close()

        #Get all of they keys into a list
        $softwareKeys = @()
        if ($is64){
            $pathUninstall64 = "SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
            $keyUninstall64 = $reg.OpenSubKey($pathUninstall64)
            $keyUninstall64.GetSubKeyNames() | % {
                $softwareKeys += $pathUninstall64 + "\\" + $_
            }
            $keyUninstall64.Close()
        }
        $pathUninstall32 = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
        $keyUninstall32 = $reg.OpenSubKey($pathUninstall32)
        $keyUninstall32.GetSubKeyNames() | % {
            $softwareKeys += $pathUninstall32 + "\\" + $_
        }
        $keyUninstall32.Close()

        #Get information from all the keys
        $softwareKeys | % {
            $subkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($_)
            if ($subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")){
                $installDate = $null
                if ($subkey.GetValue("InstallDate") -match "/"){
                    $installDate = Get-Date $subkey.GetValue("InstallDate")
                }
                elseif ($subkey.GetValue("InstallDate").length -eq 8){
                    $installDate = Get-Date $subkey.GetValue("InstallDate").Insert(6,".").Insert(4,".")
                }
                New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    ComputerName = $Computer
                    Name = $subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")
                    Version = $subKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
                    Vendor = $subkey.GetValue("Publisher")
                    UninstallString = $subkey.GetValue("UninstallString")
                    InstallDate = $installDate
                }
            }

            $subkey.Close()
        }
        $reg.Close()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That's certainly useful. I took your process and stripped it way down, since I only need the version of a single software install, not every installed package.

Comment: So the next step in the process is using this in other domains. My script works great for servers in the same domain as my workstation, but I support servers in a dozen domains...

Answer (score 1):

That Get-RemoteSoftware works great--assuming remote registry service is started on the remote system. If not you will get an error. I always check if this is started and start it if not, then stop it when done. I wonder if this is why the otherwise-great function received down-votes.

Here is a slightly modified version that will check and start the remote registry service, and stop when finished.

```
Function Get-WmiCustom2([string]$computername,[string]$namespace,[string]$class,[int]$timeout=15,[string]$whereclause='') 
{
#Function Get-WMICustom2 by MSFT's Daniele Muscetta 
#This is a modified version to add where clause parameter, optional
#Original function: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmuscett/archive/2009/05/27/get_2d00_wmicustom.aspx

$ConnectionOptions = new-object System.Management.ConnectionOptions
$EnumerationOptions = new-object System.Management.EnumerationOptions
$timeoutseconds = new-timespan -seconds $timeout
$EnumerationOptions.set_timeout($timeoutseconds)
$assembledpath = "\\" + $computername + "\" + $namespace

$Scope = new-object System.Management.ManagementScope $assembledpath, $ConnectionOptions

try {
    $Scope.Connect()
} catch {
    $result="Error Connecting " + $_
    return $Result 
}

$querystring = "SELECT * FROM " + $class + " " + $whereclause
$query = new-object System.Management.ObjectQuery $querystring
$searcher = new-object System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
$searcher.set_options($EnumerationOptions)
$searcher.Query = $querystring
$searcher.Scope = $Scope

trap { $_ } $result = $searcher.get()

return $result
}

Function Get-RemoteSoftware{
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
Displays all software listed in the registry on a given computer.

.DESCRIPTION
Uses the SOFTWARE registry keys (both 32 and 64bit) to list the name, version, vendor, and uninstall string for each software entry on a given computer.

.EXAMPLE
C:\PS> Get-RemoteSoftware -ComputerName SERVER1
This shows the software installed on SERVER1.
#>

param (
[Parameter(mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string[]]
# Specifies the computer name to connect to
$ComputerName
)

Process {
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
    {
        $ChangeStateBack=$False
        $RemoteRegistryObj=""
        $ServiceWMIObj=@(get-wmicustom2 -class "win32_service" -namespace "root\cimv2" -whereclause "WHERE name='RemoteRegistry'" -computername $computername –timeout 60 -erroraction stop)
        if ($ServiceWMIObj.Count -gt 0) {
        $RemoteRegistryObj =  $ServiceWMIObj[0]
        if ($RemoteRegistryObj.State -ne 'Running') {
                $ChangeStateBack=$true
                $RemoteRegistryObj.InvokeMethod("StartService",$null) | Out-Null
                Start-Sleep -m 1800     
                #give it a chance to actually start. 1.5 second delay
        }
}
    #Open Remote Base
    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer)

    #Check if it's got 64bit regkeys
    $keyRootSoftware = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
    [bool]$is64 = ($keyRootSoftware.GetSubKeyNames() | ? {$_ -eq 'WOW6432Node'} | Measure-Object).Count
    $keyRootSoftware.Close()

    #Get all of they keys into a list
    $softwareKeys = @()
    if ($is64){
        $pathUninstall64 = "SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
        $keyUninstall64 = $reg.OpenSubKey($pathUninstall64)
        $keyUninstall64.GetSubKeyNames() | % {
            $softwareKeys += $pathUninstall64 + "\\" + $_
        }
        $keyUninstall64.Close()
    }
    $pathUninstall32 = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
    $keyUninstall32 = $reg.OpenSubKey($pathUninstall32)
    $keyUninstall32.GetSubKeyNames() | % {
        $softwareKeys += $pathUninstall32 + "\\" + $_
    }
    $keyUninstall32.Close()

    #Get information from all the keys
    $softwareKeys | % {
        $subkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($_)
        if ($subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")){
            $installDate = $null
            if ($subkey.GetValue("InstallDate") -match "/"){
                $installDate = Get-Date $subkey.GetValue("InstallDate")
            }
            elseif ($subkey.GetValue("InstallDate").length -eq 8){
                $installDate = Get-Date $subkey.GetValue("InstallDate").Insert(6,".").Insert(4,".")
            }
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                ComputerName = $Computer
                Name = $subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")
                Version = $subKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
                Vendor = $subkey.GetValue("Publisher")
                UninstallString = $subkey.GetValue("UninstallString")
                InstallDate = $installDate
            }
        }

        $subkey.Close()
    }
    $reg.Close()
    if ($ChangeStateBack){
                            $RemoteRegistryObj.InvokeMethod("StopService",$null)  | Out-Null
    }
}
}  
}
```

This is using a custom WMI get wrapper that someone at MSFT wrote, so if this snippet is copied in its entirety it will work as-is.  You could modify it back to the standard get-wmiobject function, but there is no timeout built in to that. In some [not all that rare] situations the remote WMI responder will hang indefinitely with the default WMI so this adds a timeout.
-Dane

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a follow-up *Hey! Scripting Guys* article
[Use PowerShell to Find Installed Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/) that discusses other more efficient ways to grab that information. Briefly, use one of two commands:

> ```
> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
>     Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
>     Format-Table –AutoSize
> ```
>
> ```
> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
>     Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
>     Format-Table –AutoSize
> ```

Comment: Instead of referring to external contents, let your answer include this content or atleast an example of how that content could solve the problem at hand.

Comment: thanks. the article, refernce AND the additional note saved my bacon. The solution was obvious and staring me in the face... just needed the AHA moment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [this scripting guy article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/) for why Win32_Product is bad along with alternatives, but to quote the relevant section:

> ...As it turns out, the action of querying Win32_Product has the
> potential to cause some havoc on your systems. Here is the essence of
> KB974524.
>
> The Win32_product class is not query optimized. Queries such as
> “select * from Win32_Product where (name like ‘Sniffer%’)” require WMI
> to use the MSI provider to enumerate all of the installed products and
> then parse the full list sequentially to handle the “where” clause:,
>
> This process initiates a consistency check of packages installed, and
> then verifying and repairing the installations. If you have an
> application that makes use of the Win32_Product class, you should
> contact the vendor to get an updated version that does not use this
> class.
>
> On Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, and newer operating
> systems, querying Win32_Product will trigger Windows Installer to
> perform a consistency check to verify the health of the application.
> This consistency check could cause a repair installation to occur. You
> can confirm this by checking the Windows Application Event log. You
> will see the following events each time the class is queried and for
> each product installed:

```
Event ID: 1035
Description: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: <ProductName>. 
Product Version: <VersionNumber>. Product Language: <languageID>. 
Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.
```

I usually use the Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms as we are using SCCM which installs this class. If you are not using SCCM stick with a registry query like the one @Chris N posted.

```
PS:\>Measure-Command {gwmi win32reg_addremoveprograms}
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 162
Ticks             : 1623758
TotalDays         : 1.87934953703704E-06
TotalHours        : 4.51043888888889E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.00270626333333333
TotalSeconds      : 0.1623758
TotalMilliseconds : 162.3758
```