# Searching for a program Product Code then using that to uninstall the program

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

I'm new to StackOverflow so forgive me if I've done anything wrong.

Basically what I'm trying to do is use PowerShell or just the basic command line to search for a programs product code then use that code to uninstall that program. I have basically zero knowledge of how PowerShell works, so I'm not even sure if this is possible.

I found this code that searches for product code:

```
wmic product where "Name like '%(name)%'" get IdentifyingNumber
```

It returns something like this:

**IdentifyingNumber
{EC93F20F-825C-4828-8EB9-E4C93BD0A420}**

Is there any way that that number can be pulled and put into this command?:

```
MsiExec.exe /qn /norestart /X{EC93F20F-825C-4828-8EB9-E4C93BD0A420}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But I recommend for you to start with [learning the very basics of Powershell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276). It is far beyond the scope of SO to teach you how to write basic Powershell scripts. Regardless of that - there are literally at least hundreds of examples of such a task even here on SO. These kind of questions are asked 10 times a week - please search for it. Good luck.

Comment: `msiexec /qn /norestart /X $((gcim Win32_Product -Filter "name like '%name%'").IdentifyingNumber)`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler When I replace the "name" with the basic name of the program and run it in PowerShell, there is nothing returned and the program is still there. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for helping!

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for your help! I'm going to search more on here for it, and I'm definately trying to learn powershell, I just needed this quicker than I could possibly learn it.

Comment: Does `gcim Win32_Product -Filter "name like '%name%'").IdentifyingNumber` return anything interesting? Does `gcim Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, IdentifyingNumber`? Find exacty what text it has for the name, and use that. (But NB. that Win32_Product is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25268491/478656))