# How to retrieve a list of installed software from Windows host using a custom fact in Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I created a Powershell script in order to produce custom Ansible facts on target Windows machine listing installed software. For now I can't get my software list properly parsed within my playbook.

I can see the raw content of custom facts, but it seems like JSON is not properly parsed because I can't get a proper list object to be processed by a loop statement. A fatal error occurs:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'\n\n

All custom facts (meaning Windows software list generated by Powershell custom fact) are stored automatically by Ansible within an autogenerated variable/attribute of ansible_facts called 'ansible_softwarelist' ('ansible_' suffix + name of my fact file without extension).

**Custom fact (Powershell)**

```
$software = get-wmiobject -class Win32_Product | select-object name,version,vendor
$software_count = ($software | measure).count
$software_list | % { `
    $i++

    if ($i -lt ($software_count-1))
    {
        $separator = ","
    }
    else
    {
        $separator = ""
    }

    write-host "{`"name`":`"$($_.name)`",`"version`":`"$($_.version)`",`"vendor`":`"$($_.vendor)`"}$separator"

}
```

**Raw Powershell output**

```
{"name":"Software 1","version":"14.0.7015.1000","vendor":"Vendor 1"},
{"name":"Software 2","version":"14.1.1000","vendor":"Vendor 1"},
{"name":"Software 3","version":"1.5.2","vendor":"Vendor 1"}
```

**Ansible playbook**

```
tasks:         

     - name: "Deploy Powershell script (custom Windows facts)"
       win_copy:
         src: "/etc/ansible/files/facts/softwarelist.ps1"
         dest: "C:\\remotedir\\softwarelist.ps1"

     - name: "Gather custom facts"
       setup:
         fact_path: "C:\\remotedir"

     - name: "View software list in Ansible by name"
       debug:
         msg: "{{ item.name }}"  
       loop: "{{ ansible_softwarelist }}"
```

Comment: Removing espace characters '`' and replacing all commas of "get-wmiobject" output in Powershell output produces the same error message in Ansible. Is my JSON output valid?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this just now and have few suggestions for you if you are still working on this.

1. Don't use Win32_Product class on any non-dev servers as this process also [initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying and repairing the install](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al).
2. I recommend you to take a look at the [script](https://github.com/jaapbrasser/SharedScripts/blob/master/Get-RemoteProgram/Get-RemoteProgram.ps1), to get the list of installed programs.
3. You don't need to return values of Json format from powershell script. Output of type List, Collection will do. I would actually recommend this as it would help in browsing through the cache database like mongodb if you are using one. If you return a json format output from your powershell script, the objects would be stored in string format "{"key":"value"}" in database.

Comment: The win32_product remark here is important to remember. I've seen some custom software settings get reset to default on production machines because a junior admin ran this command over multiple machines because of a repair on all msi's.

Comment: Which script do you refer to in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=TechNet-Gallery ?

Comment: What should be used in place of Win32_Product?

Comment: Updated the script link. The script didn't use the powershell functions instead it uses the registry values.

Comment: @KokHowTeh Either `Win32reg_addRemovePrograms` or `Sms_InstalledSoftware`, both of which I believe are installed by SCCM. Otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268491/alternative-to-win32-product

Comment: if you don't have SCCM, you can't use either Win32reg_addRemovePrograms or Sms_InstallSoftware.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Filter : "**| to_json**" this should format your values correctly