# GetSubKeyNames does not return all keys

Tags: c#, registry

I want to get the software installed on the client. I use WMI and the registry as well.

I find most of the information under **HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\UNINSTALL**

However, Dropbox for example, does not appear there. Dropbox is located under **HKCU** so I want to read those keys as well. Simple, I thought, cause the path is the same, just the RegistryHive changes.

**Problem**

I can not see the key **UNINSTALL** though when I'm in CurrentVersion using the function GetSubKeyNames.

```
var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32)

var key = root.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION") // works
var key = root.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\Uninstall") // doesnt work
```

Also I tried this with RegistryView.Registry64 - I get the same result.

Whats printed out when I use GetSubKeyNames is the following:

```
Device Metadata
Explorer
Group Policy
GrpConv
Internet Settings
Media Center
Run
Shell Extensions
Telephony
ThemeManager
WinTrust
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: It can be by security reason. Try to run by elevated privilege.

Comment: Your comment was helpful. I was running the application as the system user which does not have this key as this is the current user. I will iterate through the HKEY_USERS where the Uninstall key exists from now on. This way I get the software of all users. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue as well, checking both the 32-bit and 64-bit views worked.

```
        var HKLM32 = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "computername", RegistryView.Registry32);
        var HKLM64 = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "computername", RegistryView.Registry64);
        key32 = HKLM32.OpenSubKey(registryKeytoFind);
        key64 = HKLM64.OpenSubKey(registryKeytoFind);
```

Comment: Don't forget to Dispose these, or better use them inside a using statement.

Answer (score 1):

You may use: Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Your Key Here").GetSubKeyNames()

But try changing the Platform target to both x86 and x64.  You will see two different results.

To change Platform target:
Goto Project -> Properties -> Build -> Platform Target
Try setting this to X86, print results.  Then set to x64, print results

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, but problem was also that it was installer, who executed C# function. And during installation of course required key did not exists, as it was not installed.

This is very installer specific problem.