# vb.net Detect installed games on a system

Tags: vb.net, listbox, registry

i want to detect installed games on a system and show it in a listbox. I think the best thing I can do is scan specific parts of registry and look for key names that match with a List of Publishers.

But how i can do it?

Im trying this, but that's show all of programs installed.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim regkey, subkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    Dim value As String
    Dim regpath As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    regkey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regpath)
    Dim subkeys() As String = regkey.GetSubKeyNames
    Dim includes As Boolean
    For Each subk As String In subkeys
        subkey = regkey.OpenSubKey(subk)
        value = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName", "")
        If value <> "" Then
            includes = True
            If value.IndexOf("Hotfix") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Security Update") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Update for") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If includes = True Then ListBox1.Items.Add(value)

        End If
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get installed applications in a system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system)

Comment: oh dear!  someone is cranky today...

Comment: Just today? Nah, I'm always like this. :D

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå This is not what I want, I just want to show the games, or records from a list of publishers.

Comment: @ParanoidSoubhy Potato, potahto. Use an online convert like [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) or [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: @TheBlueDog Im trying with this: http://i.imgur.com/CJndkmF.png But that's show me all of programs, and i just want games, or show records from a list of publishers, like Activision etc..

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Uhm i know exist's converters, but i dont want show all of programs installed, I've already done that, I want to limit the search in the register only for games.

Comment: Mate, why don't you edit that code into your question? At least people would know what you're asking about.

Comment: @ParanoidSoubhy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @TheBlueDog I am new to using this, I will add, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå "\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2\\Applications\\Games" what is the regpath for this?