# Easy way to deploy NOT register a dll

Tags: c#, fxcop, vsix, vsx

I have a dll that I simply need other developers to add to a folder in their VS install. Specifically:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules

My first attempt (and preferred) approach was with a vsix. I just couldn't figure out how to get the .pkgdef and manifest to get along with each other and just place the file in the directory above. Googling of course was no help as everyone is coming from the angle of REGISTERING the dll so they say don't use vsix for that.

I don't want an installer class.

Install Shield too heavy...OK I could do it but seriously do I really have to go through all that?

I could email the file around and tell them where to save it to...and I'm about to do that if I can't find a simple deployment method.

Comment: Is this not a default DLL for FxCop? Is this some kind of add-in you created, or a custom set of rules?

Comment: What's the problem? They need to copy a file to a certain folder? I wouldn't bother automating that. If I did I would write some powershell to copy a file, but I don't think I would because folder locations are never that simple.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes a custom FXCop rule. I want to flag devs who are using a catch block but not Logging the error so I wrote a rule that checks catch block for logging.

Comment: Can you wait a few more months and upgrade to Visual Studio 2015?, they made static analysis rules [a lot easier to put in to projects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain....I am looking forward to 2015...however VS version is paid for by client / project...this project will be on 2010 /2013 till completion in Jan 2016...from there Absolutely I will suggest the contract renewal include 2015.

Comment: zipinstaller self extracting?  or NSIS is pretty simple and free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a program to find visual studio installation directory and copy the dll to the target location. Then send the program with the dll to the developers.
To get installation directory of a product, see [Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system).

Comment: Yeah I had that on my mind as well....I guess it's smoother than emailing around.

Comment: yuck!  a single file install is much more elegant.