# Finding if an installed application is x64

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows

I ran into this question: [Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system) to validate that a pre-requisite of my application is installed. However, I'd also like to validate whether the installed version is x64 or x86.

Is it possible?

The application I'm talking about is Microsoft Access database engine (https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: It's very crude but could you see if it's in `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` I'm sure there's a better way though

Comment: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94c2f14d-c45e-4b55-9ba0-eb091bac1035/c-get-installed-programs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94c2f14d-c45e-4b55-9ba0-eb091bac1035/c-get-installed-programs) i think this will help you

Comment: Is your real goal to determine if the 64 bit version of the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is available?  If so, you ca use a `OleDbEnumerator` to determine that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the CorFlags.exe found in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>" 
Pass the assembly as a parameter and it will list a set of flags

```
Option    | PE    | 32BIT
----------|-------|---------
x86       | PE32  | 0
Any CPU   | PE32  | 1
x64       | PE32+ | 0
```

Hope that helps.