# C# On windows, how to get a list of installed programs' directories

Tags: c#, windows

So I found the solution of getting a list of installed programs from here. [Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system)

But I wonder if I can get the installed directory of each of them? I need it because i would need to find all the executable files for that program.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try checking the subkeys' `InstallLocation` value - it should be present at least for non driver/printer/etc. stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find all installed app from

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Here is the sample code:

```
private string FindByDisplayName(RegistryKey parentKey, string name)
{
    string[] nameList = parentKey.GetSubKeyNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Length; i++)
    {
        RegistryKey regKey =  parentKey.OpenSubKey(nameList[i]);
        try
        {
            if (regKey.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() == name)
            {
                return regKey.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    return "";
}

RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
string location = FindByDisplayName(regKey, "MSN");
MessageBox.Show(location);
```

This example will compare the `DisplayName` key value to your input name, if it finds the value, then return the `InstallLocation` key value.

Comment: TLDR: The solution is to use Key: InstallLocation instead of Key: DisplayName