# Is it possible to, with a C# program, get a list of PDF readers installed on a given PC?

Tags: c#

I need to list all the PDF readers available in a given PC.
I've found many ways to get the default one, or to get just the adobe acrobat, but I need to be able to list them all like:
Adobe Acrobat
Foxit
...

Comment: You can loop through the rigistry, but you would need a list of the programs to do the comparison - see here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/908907/3739842

Comment: Also, Explorer file type (extension) associations are stored in the registry somewhere, but I forget the details.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Can you list which program is associated with .pdf?  A: Yes.

Q: Can you loop through all installed programs, and print out those which read .pdfs?

A: Yes ... but *you* need to make a list of "which programs read .pdfs".  Windows doesn't know this a priori.

PS:
You should probably also include Chrome and Firefox (among others) in your list.