# How to discover the main executable file of an application

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-installer

I am installing applications programatically in an unattended fashion ( nothing special, just passing the paramters "/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART" if exe, or "msiexec /qn /i ALLUSERS=1" while is an msi file ).

The problem is after installation suceded I want to open the application I've just installed. Then I am looking for a way to discover the main executable file of an application I've just installed.

I've tried monitoring harddisk and also checking on registry but I hasn't found anything robust and universal.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you checked in the registry?

Comment: In general you can't do this because there is no hard pattern that must be followed. What you need to do is find a different way to tackle the problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've been checking on list for uninstall at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall but it's not exposing the path to exe file in most of cases.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what I am creating is somehow an "store" application, which allows to install apps into the system and also open them.. could you point me in right direction ? :)

Comment: There is not direction, neither left nor right nor right nor wrong. This problem doesn't have a solution.

Comment: There's a collection of application paths at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

Comment: If I repeat what I said before, will you read it this time?

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks I'll check if this could improve my solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have asked again as you pointed to find a different way to tackle the problem. 

Apologizes if I have missunderstood your answer, then I'll keep the point of there's no a way to do this and maybe I need to ask, apart of the installer, to provide the entry point or so..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a suitable way, I hope this could help anyone else.

There's an special hidden shell object in Windows 10 who list all the applications (UWP and regular) that gets open in this way:

- Win + R
- Put Shell:AppsFolder and execute it.

Then it's a question of getting the list there programatically and checking what have changed after installation.

This is achieved in this way (It's needed [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) nuget package):

```
var appsFolderId = new Guid("{1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58}");
IKnownFolder appsFolder = KnownFolderHelper.FromKnownFolderId(appsFolderId);
foreach (var app in appsFolder)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{app.Name} {app.ParsingName}");
}
```

app.Name is the name of the app, and app.ParsingName is the name that can be used to open the application using this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @" shell:appsFolder\" + app.ParsingName);
```

If needed, you can get the icon of the app through this property:

```
app.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmapSource
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system/57195200#57195200) for the solution.

Then now is a question of storing the current list, install the new app and check changes on that list after. Also as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system/57195200#57195200) suggests; you can listen for changes on that shellobject to get notified while the change is effective, with this:

```
ShellObjectWatcher watcher = new ShellObjectWatcher(appsFolder, false);
watcher.AllEvents += <Your_events_handler>;
watcher.Start();
```