# how to get list of installed programs on client ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to know how to get list of installed programs on client desktop using ASP.NET or html overall

Thank you

Comment: We would now if any website could freely and silently scan one's hard disk and grab all the data it wanted to send it back to whomever :) This is impossible to do with HTML for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get installed applications in a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  It would be a security risk if it did exist.

To get the list of installed programs, you need to have some kind of agent run on the user's computer and upload it to your server.  There are lots of services that work like this.